# How to recover the Ripple effect on gradient background

Tags: xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm making a note app. I started with design, so I don't have any code yet. I made a button with an image of a "+" and a gradient background, but ended up losing the ripple effect. I saw some with similar problems, but I didn't understand anything. **How do I recover the ripple effect?** Currently, it only works on the image, but I want it on the entire button, including the background.

**add_button_design.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient android:startColor="#706fd3" android:endColor="#34ace0" android:angle="45"/>
      <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
      <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#227093"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/add_button_image"/>
  </item>

  <item>
    <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_image"/>
    </ripple>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_button_design"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know this can be considered a duplicate question, but the others don't fit my plans.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the `selector` in your `ripple` tag. Here is running GIF.
[image]

Here is code.

```
   <layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient android:startColor="#706fd3" android:endColor="#34ace0" android:angle="45"/>
      <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
      <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#227093"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/add_button_image"/>
  </item>

  <item>
    <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
      <!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_image"/>-->

     <selector>
       <!-- unclick the background-->
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_image"
            android:state_pressed="false" />
     <!-- click the background-->
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_image"
            android:state_pressed="true" />
      </selector>
    </ripple>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @Um Canal Qualquer If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer. it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

using the @Leon base, I managed to fix it. Just put everything inside the **Ripple** Tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <item>
    <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
      <item>
        <shape>
          <gradient android:startColor="#706fd3" android:endColor="#34ace0" android:angle="45"/>
          <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
          <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#227093"/>
        </shape>
      </item>

      <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/add_button_image"/>
      </item>
    </ripple>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```